# Scaling a tikzpicture in the figure environment with caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, scaling

I want to scale a tikzpicture within the figure environment.
The code that produces the scaled figure:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\tikzstyle{ball} = [circle,shading=ball, ball color=blue!60!white]
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pgflowlevelsynccm
\foreach \a in {1,...,6}
    {
    \node[style=ball] (r\a) at (1.5*\a,0) {\textcolor{yellow}{$\mu_\a$}};
    \draw[very thick] (r\a)--(1.5*\a,1.75);
    \draw[very thick] (r\a)--(1.5*\a,-1.75);
    \ifthenelse{\a = 6}
        {}
        {\draw[very thick] (r\a)--(1.5+1.5*\a,0);}
    }
\draw[line width=5mm,draw=green] (0.5,-1) rectangle (10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{M1} \label{fig:M1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces a tikz picture that is correctly scaled, but now overlaps with the caption: 
[image]

Is there any way around this?

Also, is it possible to rescale the tikzpicture with respect to the textwidth with something like

```
0.5\textwidth
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For rescaling in general you can use a `resizebox` (from the `graphicx` package), which also works for `tikzpicture`. The first argument is the width, the second the height, or `!` to scale proportionally. With a `resizebox` you don't need coordinate transformation, which seems to cause the overlap in your example.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikzscale}
\tikzstyle{ball} = [circle,shading=ball, ball color=blue!60!white]
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\resizebox{0.3\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\pgflowlevelsynccm
\foreach \a in {1,...,6}
    {
    \node[style=ball] (r\a) at (1.5*\a,0) {\textcolor{yellow}{$\mu_\a$}};
    \draw[very thick] (r\a)--(1.5*\a,1.75);
    \draw[very thick] (r\a)--(1.5*\a,-1.75);
    \ifthenelse{\a = 6}
        {}
        {\draw[very thick] (r\a)--(1.5+1.5*\a,0);}
    }
\draw[line width=5mm,draw=green] (0.5,-1) rectangle (10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{M1} \label{fig:M1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This solution works beautifully and solves all my problems!

Comment: @GrimReaper, scaling is evil. Now you have text in image so small that it can be read only with magnifying glass ... is this really what you want?

Comment: @Zarko , thanks for the heads up! In this case, fortunately for me, this figure is a generalization of a larger one in my document. Thanks for the tip though!